# Running DelayedJob worker causes rails app to hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job, puma

I have a Rails app deployed to Heroku. It currently has a 2x web dyno, and a 1x worker dyno. No active users at this point other than myself.

When the worker dyno is running, I get frequent H12 errors on `app/web.1`. When the worker stops, the errors stop.

Within the app, a user can upload a CSV file, and then DelayedJob runs a service on a worker that parses the CSV file, and saves `Contact`, `EmailAddress` and `PhoneNumber` objects to the database. There's some deduplication and some merging logic as well.

The worker runs flawlessly. But while it's running, I have a lot of trouble using the app. Most attempts to load a page end up timing out, and I see entries like this in the log:

```
Mar 31 10:52:54 abb heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/contacts" host=abb.herokuapp.com request_id=a061e6b1-0233-4be1-9653-5db023d339ac fwd="99.17.86.166" dyno=web.1 connect=17ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 
Mar 31 10:53:18 abb heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=abb.herokuapp.com request_id=73d1e9e4-2e93-4e63-a86e-c8f90d22d172 fwd="50.250.42.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 
Mar 31 10:53:39 abb heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/contacts" host=abb.herokuapp.com request_id=83753eec-774b-4939-8ad5-3b5876c14151 fwd="99.17.86.166" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30012ms status=503 bytes=0 
Mar 31 10:53:49 abb heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abb.herokuapp.com request_id=575492b9-e997-4be5-8044-1be37ec2eda6 fwd="50.250.42.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I'm using Ruby 2.3, Rails 4.2.5.1, Postgres for the database, and I have the same problems with both Unicorn and Puma. Any ideas why the worker causing these issues?

## Update

I discovered that I'm getting the same problem when I run the app locally in both development and production modes. When the worker is processing a CSV file, the app hangs.

Comment: Could it be database concurrency? EG: database is being locked while the worker processes data. If you haven't seen this yet, it's a good read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Comment: @Rots - thanks for the great article! I'm not getting any ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError(s) - any idea how to tell if the DB is being locked while the worker is running?

Comment: Definitely a database issue. The Contacts, EmailAddresses and PhoneNumbers tables are locking until the job is completed.